# How to find element in matrix using Opencv

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am novice in OpenCV. I want to use equality operator between a vector element and matrix to cross check where both values are equal or not. How do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean e.g. where one matrix row is completely identical to the whole vector?

Comment: @Micka both of them entirely differ in values except some elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want to compare one element of the vector to one element of the matrix this could be done in the following way:

```cpp
cv::Vec3b vec(1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat mat(2, 2, CV_8UC1);
if (vec[0] == mat.at<uchar>(2, 1)) {
    ...
}
```

This compares the first element of a uchar vector to the second-row, first-column element of a uchar matrix.

If you want to iterate over the matrix, do it the following way:

```cpp
cv::Mat mat(2, 2, CV_8UC1);
uchar* ptr;
for (int row = 0; row < mat.rows; ++row) {
    ptr = mat.ptr<uchar>(row);
    for (int col = 0; cols < mat.cols; ++col) {
        if(ptr[col] == ...)
    }
}
```

EDIT: equivalent for float, just exchange `uchar` for `float`:

```cpp
cv::Vec3f vec(1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat mat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
if (vec[0] == mat.at<float>(2, 1)) {
    ...
}
```

And:

```cpp
cv::Mat mat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
float* ptr;
for (int row = 0; row < mat.rows; ++row) {
    ptr = mat.ptr<float>(row);
    for (int col = 0; cols < mat.cols; ++col) {
        if(ptr[col] == ...)
    }
}
```

If you have multiple channels `ptr[col]` returns not one value but an OpenCV vector of the matrix' data type and as many dimensions as you've got channels. You can also directly add another `[]` operator with the index of the channel you want to access:

```cpp
if(ptr[col][channel] == ...)
```

### How to find out the data type of your cv::Mat?

From the type and depth specifier of your matrix you can see what data type they store:

> - CV_8U - 8-bit unsigned integers ( 0..255 )
> - CV_8S - 8-bit signed integers ( -128..127 )
> - CV_16U - 16-bit unsigned integers ( 0..65535 )
> - CV_16S - 16-bit signed integers ( -32768..32767 )
> - CV_32S - 32-bit signed integers ( -2147483648..2147483647 )
> - CV_32F - 32-bit floating-point numbers ( -FLT_MAX..FLT_MAX, INF, NAN )
> - CV_64F - 64-bit floating-point numbers ( -DBL_MAX..DBL_MAX, INF, NAN )

These are the depth specifiers for matrices. You can find out the depth of your matrix by calling `cv::Mat::depth()`. They specify which data type one element has. The type specifiers you use when creating a matrix also contain the information how many channels the matrix shall have, just add `Cx` to the depth specifier, `x` being the amount of channels , e.g. `CV_8UC3` would be a matrix with three channels and 8bit unsigned chars as data type (so a pretty normal 8bit image). This information can be obtained from an existing matrix by calling `cv::Mat::type()`. The amount of channels is returned by `cv::Mat::channels()`.

For OpenCV Vectors those type specifiers are similar:

> ```cpp
> typedef Vec<uchar, 2> Vec2b;
> typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;
> typedef Vec<uchar, 4> Vec4b;
>
> typedef Vec<short, 2> Vec2s;
> typedef Vec<short, 3> Vec3s;
> typedef Vec<short, 4> Vec4s;
>
> typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i;
> typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
> typedef Vec<int, 4> Vec4i;
>
> typedef Vec<float, 2> Vec2f;
> typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
> typedef Vec<float, 4> Vec4f;
> typedef Vec<float, 6> Vec6f;
>
> typedef Vec<double, 2> Vec2d;
> typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
> typedef Vec<double, 4> Vec4d;
> typedef Vec<double, 6> Vec6d;
> ```

Comment: is it necessary that vector element must be in uchar, since mat has uchar format??

Comment: i am getting assertion error...since mine vector element is in float format

Comment: I edited my answer and included the example for floats. Basically you just have to change all `uchar` occurences to `float`.